# How can I delete a file with extension ".." in windows

Tags: windows, file

## I mistakenly created a large file on a windows drive mounted in a linux using touch.

```
touch /mnt/<my_win_drive>/my_super_file...
```

Notice that the file extension is in ".."
I am using windows 7 but I assume it should be the same for all windows versions.

### Now I can easily remove it from linux:

```
rm /mnt/<my_win_drive>/my_super_file...
```

### But if I try to remove it from explorer then it fails miserably saying that he cannot find the file:

```
Could not find this item
This is no longer located in <my_win_drive>
Verify the item's location and try again.
```

### If I try using cmd, it's all the same:

```
cd <my_win_drive> 
rm my_super_file... (note that tab-autocomplete works)
rm: cannot lstat `my_super_file...': No such file or directory
```

---

**So what's the big deal if one can delete the file from linux you'd ask.**

**Well, the problem is that windows explorer allows you to copy such a file.**
In my particular case, my_super_file was not created by touch but is actually a 4Gb file that I copied with the wrong name on my shared_drive, then on my desktop.
Now I a am stuck with a large file that I cannot move from my desktop.

Any idea how to get rid of it other than formatting my drive?

Comment: try `del "\\?\c:\pathtoyour\file.."`

Comment: same old unfortunately: Could Not Find <file>

Comment: Sure the name is correct? If I create `"foo.."` with `dir > "\\?\c:\temp\foo.."` I can then `del "\\?\c:\temp\foo.."`

Comment: My extension is ".." so the file name is "my_file..." (3 dots).   
My explorer automatically removes the dots if I try to rename a legit file. As I explained, I had to use linux to create the file, then copy it on a shared windows drive.

Comment: Still works for me with `...`. Try `dir "c:\path" /x` and note the short 8.3 name `(file~barf)` then `del "file~barf"`

Comment: Are you also using win7? I'm curious to see how you create the file.

Anyway your solution worked! thanks a lot!

Can you put your solution as an anwser so I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: Yes, win7.  `echo Hello > \\?\c:\temp\xxx...` would create `"xxx..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use the `\\?\` syntax which will bypass the usual file parsing rules:

   ```
   del "\\?\c:\pathtoyour\file..."
   ```
2. Capture the legacy 8.3 name with `dir path /x` then delete:

   ```
   del "file~id"
   ```